# Render icon in R shiny based on condition

Tags: r, shiny, icons

I am trying to render icons in my shiny dashboard based on a particular condition. Below is the code I am using to get the if else working . Since my code base is too big to share I am just posting the code for that particular portion:

```
output$cost_compare <-renderUI( ifelse(
  last_week$cost < kpi_table$cost,
  as.character(icon("angle-up")),
  as.character(icon("angle-down"))
))
```

```
compareCostUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  ( uiOutput(ns("cost_compare")))
}
```

And I am using this in the ui inside a descriptionblock. Below is the code for it

```
descriptionBlock(
                     number = compareCostUI("pacing"))
```

What I am missing here due to which I can see the icon rendered

Comment: Can you provide a "full" (but small) sample rmarkdown/shiny app? As minimal as possible is preferred, but enough so that we don't need to contrive an app to surround your code. Thanks!

Comment: For wahtever reason, `htmlOutput` function works better when returning a character of actual html elements. Try replacing that.
If that doesn't work, see if you can get this working without using `compareCostUI`, and instead just specifying an `htmlOutput` element in the ui function.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore my last comment:

Using `renderText` is what you want to use if you are passing html strings to the UI. Returning character values in renderUI returns literal strings. Seems unintuitive. 
I'm not sure if your `compareCostUI` function is causing any issues and I also didn't know the namespace of `descriptionBlock` but I made a small reproducible example of rendering an icon.

I'm also assuming that your two values `last_week` and `kpi_table` are reactive in some way? otherwise the `output$cost_compare` would actually never update.

```
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("Press","press", icon = icon("refresh")),
    uiOutput("cost_compare")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$cost_compare <- renderText({
    if(input$Press%%2==0){
      condition <- T
    } else{
      condition <-F
    }
    ifelse(condition,
            as.character(icon("angle-up")), as.character(icon("angle-down")))

  }

  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```